# Ubuntu 13.04. How configure surround sound?

Tags: sound, 13.04

My Xonar DX 7.1 sound card thinks that it has only 2 channels. 
In 12.10 I modified /etc/pulse/daemon.conf file.

http://www.webupd8.org/2009/06/enable-surround-sound-in-ubuntu-linux.html

I changed default-sample-channels = 8 but can't see no changes in Sound settings.

[image]

Does anybody had the same problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found solution. Just installed pavucontrol from Software Center and set my sound card configuration as 7.1. Now sound works fine!
Strange it's not possible to do it from Sound Settings and it is required to install additional software to choose your sound scheme.